# How to debug the error "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")

# Find multiple elements
elements = driver.find_element("name", "q")

elements.send_keys('ChromeDriver')

elements.submit()

# Loop over the elements
for element in elements:
    # Loop over the sub-elements
    for sub_element in element:
        print(sub_element)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `find_elements` to get all the matching elements.

Comment: Where the code says `driver.find_element("name", "q")`, it seems that you expect this (according to the code comment) to `# Find multiple elements`. **Why**? Did you try reading the documentation? Did you try to *check* what result you get? Aside from that, it's not at all clear what you hope to accomplish with the `.send_keys` and `.submit` calls.

Answer (score 0):

`find_element` returns a single matched `WebElement` object which is not iteratable. You should check out the method [find_elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) as suggested by @Unmitigated for the driver to get a collection of matched elements which will then allows you iterate through using `for` loop above

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
elements = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'q')

for element in elements:
   # Do something
```